# preg_match on a result of previous preg_match

Tags: php

I have this code, which goes through an string and outputs the first img´s `src=""` attribute.

I need to get out the `alt=""` attribute too.

```
$first_image = '';
if ((preg_match('/<img[^>]*>/i', $article_fulltext, $matches ) == 1))
if (preg_match('/src="([^"]*)"/', $matches[0], $morematches ) == 1)
$first_image = $morematches[0];
```

What I´ve tried, but diden´t work;

```
$first_image = '';
if ((preg_match('/<img[^>]*>/i', $article_fulltext, $matches ) == 1))
if (preg_match('/src="([^"]*)"/', $matches[0], $morematches ) == 1)
if (preg_match('/alt="([^"]*)"/', $matches[0], $morematchesAlt ) == 1)
$first_image = $morematches[0];
$first_image_alt = $morematchesAlt[0];
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You probably need braces round the bit in the final `if`, it's OK to miss them out with 1 statement, but 2 statements need braces.

Comment: I would also recommend trying to use something like DOMDocument rather than regex to process HTML.

Comment: @NigelRen Thanks! You mean like `if ((`? ...I actually don´t understand why the first line has the double `((` I took the code from an example

Comment: More like `... $morematchesAlt ) == 1)   {` ... `$morematchesAlt[0];  }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree about opinion that you'd rather use DOMDocument, but with purpose to use your code, you have to change it little bit, like this:

```
<?php

$article_fulltext = '<html><body><img src="imgSrc" alt="imgAlt"></body></html>';

if (preg_match('/<img[^>]*>/i', $article_fulltext, $matches)) {
    preg_match('/src="([^"]*)"/', $matches[0], $morematches);
    preg_match('/alt="([^"]*)"/', $matches[0], $morematchesAlt);

    $first_image = $morematches[0];
    $first_image_alt = $morematchesAlt[0];

    var_dump($first_image);
    var_dump($first_image_alt);
}
```

When you run this script - you receive next result:

```
string(12) "src="imgSrc""
string(12) "alt="imgAlt""
```

Comment: Thanks!!.. Is this also checking if `src` and if `alt` exist? Now that the if line is gone from those two

Comment: @JonasB Yes. In case `$article_fulltext` contains image it will check `src` & `alt`.

Comment: @JonasB Welcome any time 

Answer (score 1):

Your code suffers from lack of braces to correctly define the structure of your conditional statements. Whenever you use multiple statements under an `if` clause, it's advisable to use braces to prevent them from nesting and producing undesired effects.

Also, as it has already been mentioned, regular expressions aren't the best way to parse HTML, so here's a solution using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
<?php
    # Create a new DOMDocument instance and load the html content.
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom -> loadHTML($article_fulltext);

    # Cache the first image element.
    $img = $dom -> getElementsByTagName("img") -> item(0);

    # Print its 'src' and 'alt' attributes.
    echo $img -> getAttribute("src");
    echo $img -> getAttribute("alt");
?>
```

Comment: Using [getAttribute](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) would be worth looking at.

Comment: Yeah, sure @NigelRen! I just use `attributes -> getNamedItem(...) -> value` in my code, because usually, I need to cache the attributes object separately.

Comment: Thanks! Great to know :-)